# If one of the object to be written has the same content as the one in Firestore, what will happen?

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write to two different `Documents` at the same time so I use a `Firestore Transaction` to insure they get written right away.

My question is if one of the `Object` to be written has the same content as the one in Firestore, what will happen, will the write still happen or will the `transaction` only write the other `Object` since its different.

If I do 10 `transaction` and 5 of them write the same `data`, is it possible to not write duplicate data to save bandwidth if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is if one of the objects to be written has the same content as the one in Firestore, what will happen, will the write operation still happen?

Yes, it will. The write will be performed and besides that, you'll also be charged.

> If I do 10 transactions and 5 of them write the same data, is it possible to not write duplicate data to save bandwidth if so how?

Yes, it is possible, by checking if the document exists. In this case, there will not be a write operation involved but a read operation, which is cheaper. So you won't be charged for a write operation anymore, you'll only have to pay for a single read operation. So in Cloud Firestore, everything is about the read/write operations you perform. See here [Cloud Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

Comment: Hi Erik!Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Does overwriting identical data on a document count as another write? Since Firestore doesn't have to update its index.

Comment: @SlickSlime Yes it does count.